# Binding an IQueryable to Infragistics XamDataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, infragistics, xamdatagrid

Is it possible to bind an IQueryable of T to a XamDataGrid. So that the grid does paging (loading on demand) or column ordering automatically? How can I achieve this?

There is a DataSource property, but it takes an IEnumerable which does not help cause it loads all data on the client before filtering.